# Is it possible to set the dimensions of a jdialog as equal as those of a jtable put in it?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JDialog with a JTable putting inside it, i'd like to know if it's possible to set the Jdialog dimension(width and height) using the JTable dimension, not more space. For example the dialog's height would have to be the same height of the table put in it, without free space. Until now i have setted the dialog's dimension using the method setSize but if my table's rows don't completely occupy all the space then the height will have free space. I want to view only the space occupied by the table;

```
JDialog d=new JDialog();
String columns[]={"Name","Surname","year of birth"};
Object rows[][]={{"Mario","rossi","1992"}};
JTable t=new JTable(rows,columns);
d.setSize(200,200);
d.add(t);
d.setVisible(true);
```

In the above code i've setted a specific dimension for d, but in this way it could be more space exceeding in height and width!!! someone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is no (or not quite).  A decorated window also has window borders and other "decorations" which will always make the window larger then the content.

The best solution you have to is use `JDialog#pack`, which will pack the frame around the preferred size of the content.

You should also know that it's pointless using `setSize` on components which are under the control of a layout manager.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

```
JDialog d=new JDialog();
String columns[]={"Name","Surname","year of birth"};
Object rows[][]={{"Mario","rossi","1992"}};
JTable t=new JTable(rows,columns);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
d.add(new JScrollPane(t));
d.pack();
d.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Great!! it works , thank you very much!!! to fit the dialog to exact height of the table i've setted the height value of the object Dimension with t.getRowHeight()*rows.length!!!

Answer (score 2):

Don't explicitly set the size - let the LayoutManager manage it for you by calling `pack` on the `JDialog` after adding all the components:

```
d.add(t);
d.pack();
d.setVisible(true);
```